# Email HTML content is not centering

Tags: html, css, email

My email is comprised of a set of images - some full-width rows containing a full-width image, while other full-width rows contain two 50%-width images.
The single-asset rows are centering, but the 2-asset rows are not.

Any suggestions as to how to address this?

```
<table width="100%" bgcolor="#F9F8F8" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" align="center" style="padding:0;margin:0;border-collapse:collapse;mso-table-lspace:0pt;mso-table-rspace:0pt;">
        <!-- SINGLE-WIDE Image, Flush : BEGIN -->

        <tr>
            <td class="full-width-image" align="center" style="mso-table-lspace:0 !important;mso-table-rspace:0 !important;">
                <a href="https://mizmooz.ca/collections/spring-collection"><img src="https://gallery.mailchimp.com/df9c3a35085c40dd1033b83bf/images/0f9cfabb-011b-4af6-9962-0d097a3a884a.jpg" width="800" alt="" border="0" style="width: 100%;max-width: 800px;height: auto;display: block;vertical-align: text-top;" class="img-fullwidth"></a>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="full-width-image" align="center" style="mso-table-lspace:0 !important;mso-table-rspace:0 !important;">
                <a href="https://mizmooz.ca/collections/under-75"><img src="https://gallery.mailchimp.com/df9c3a35085c40dd1033b83bf/images/c3fa45e0-1954-491a-b567-a0f39b19ea15.jpg" width="800" alt="" border="0" style="width: 100%;max-width: 800px;height: auto;display: block;vertical-align: text-top;" class="img-fullwidth"></a>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <!-- SINGLE-WIDE Image: END -->
        <!-- DOUBLE-WIDE Image, Flush : BEGIN -->
        <tr style="display:block;">
            <td class="full-width-image" align="center" style="mso-table-lspace:0 !important;mso-table-rspace:0 !important;">
                <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" width="100%" >
                    <tr>
                        <td class="stack-column-center" align="center">
                            <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" width="100%">
                                <tr>
                                    <td style="padding:0px;text-align:center;">
                                        <a href="https://mizmooz.ca/collections/under-75/products/air-04"><img src="https://gallery.mailchimp.com/df9c3a35085c40dd1033b83bf/images/80c28595-a6cc-43e1-9e5c-f581a77064f7.jpg" width="400" alt="" border="0" class="fluid" style="display: block;"></a>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            </table>
                        </td>
                        <td class="stack-column-center">
                            <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0">
                                <tr>
                                    <td style="padding:0px;text-align:center;">
                                        <a href="https://mizmooz.ca/collections/under-75/products/april-s16"><img src="https://gallery.mailchimp.com/df9c3a35085c40dd1033b83bf/images/9e708022-b8f2-4528-89b0-95b51dd73caa.jpg" width="400" alt="" border="0" class="fluid" style="display: block;"></a>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            </table>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

Comment: Not sure why the downvotes, but any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Why do you place a `<table>` inside a `<td>`?